# How can I run python script inside a frame in tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frame, tk-toolkit

I have a function that asks the user to answer a couple of question which prints out a result I have written my code inside a function called Script and I made it so when I press a button the function runs but in my terminal while I want it to run inside the frame I created

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def Script():
    #My script/code is written here

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(background = "#110a60")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 750, width = 800, bg = "#110a60")
canvas.pack()

root.resizable(False, False)
 
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = "black")
frame.place(relheight = 0.8, relwidth = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

start_button = Button(root, text = 'Start Program', padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = Script)
start_button.place(x = 350, y = 680)

exit_button = Button(root, text = 'Exit', padx = 20, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = exit)
exit_button.place(x = 368, y = 714.5 )

root.mainloop()
```

So how can I make it when I press the Start program button the text and input outputting to the terminal/console be printed inside the [frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQKla.png) I made(inside the red borders)

And Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't. print() is for the console.

More elaborate answer:

You'll probably need a Label() widget for your questions and a Entry() widget for user input. Also your script() function should not print but return a string which you can then display in a Text() widget.

Edit (added some code to your code to get you going):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, Button, Label, Entry, StringVar, Text

def my_script():
    questions=["What is your name?",
               "What is your age?"]
    answers = []
    answer_box.config(background='grey')
    answer_box.focus()
    for question in questions:
        question_label.config(text=question)
        answer_box.wait_variable(answer_given)
        answers.append(answer_box.get())
        answer_box.delete(0, 'end')
        answer_box.focus()
    for answer in answers:
        print_area.insert('end', answer+"\n")

root = Tk()
root.configure(background = "#110a60")

canvas = Canvas(root, height = 750, width = 800, bg = "#110a60")
canvas.pack()

root.resizable(False, False)
 
frame = Frame(root, bg = "black")
frame.place(relheight = 0.8, relwidth = 0.8, relx = 0.1, rely = 0.1)

start_button = Button(root, text = 'Start Program', padx = 10, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = my_script)
start_button.place(x = 350, y = 680)

exit_button = Button(root, text = 'Exit', padx = 20, pady = 5, fg = "#FFFF00", bg = "#012456", command = exit)
exit_button.place(x = 368, y = 714.5 )

question_label = Label(frame, text="", bg='black', fg='white')
question_label.place(relx=0.5, y=80, anchor='center')

answer_given = StringVar()
answer_box = Entry(frame, bg='black', borderwidth=0)
answer_box.place(relx=0.5, y=110, anchor='center')
answer_box.bind('<Return>', lambda x: answer_given.set("foobar"))

print_area = Text(frame, bg='black', fg='white')
print_area.place(relx=0.5, y=180, height=300, width=500, anchor='n')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So every print and input used in my function have to be changed ?

Comment: Yes. In it's current state it's not going to do what you want.

Comment: @UnknownAsker i added some code to my answer. This is not a great coding example but it's probably good enough to get you going.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try to match my code and make it work but its a big script and running it and how it will function is depending on user choice so its going to be very hard for me to get it but I will try

Comment: You can get it done.  :)